# Insert int to database from Csharp windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have a program im righting to handle stock and sales.

My add stock form takes the description price and sale price and adds to a database,

my problem is that when inserting the prices into the database they get rounded and miss the numbers after the decimal place.

The code i have wrote up to now is here,

```
    private void AddStockButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < QtyNumber.Value; )
        {
            try
            {
                if (ItemDescription.Text == "") // check if textbox is empty
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You havent given the item a description"); // if the text box is empty show a message box
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                if (ItemGroupList.SelectedIndex == -1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("A Group must be selected");
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                if (PurchasePriceBox.Value == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Purchase Price cannot be 0");
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                if (SalePriceBox.Value == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Sale Price cannot be 0");
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                if (PurchasePriceBox.Value >= SalePriceBox.Value)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot sell for less that purchase price");
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Stocked_Items ([Item Description], [Purchase Price], [Purchase Date], [Group], [Sale Price]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", Program.DB_CONNECTION); // add the information into the database
                com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", ItemDescription.Text));
                com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", PurchasePriceBox.Value));
                com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", DateTime.Today.Date));
                com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", group[ItemGroupList.SelectedIndex].ID));
                com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", SalePriceBox.Value));

                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Can anyone help me insert the full price including decimal figures (1.99 example would currentley be inserted as 2 and id like it to go as 1.99)

Cheers

Comment: whats the datatype of column storing price in ms-access?

Comment: Have you tried setting a `size` and `precision` on the `OleDbParamater`?

Comment: make it as single or double and try

Comment: try reading this to see how to set the param data type in regards to your Parameter.Add method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by doing two things.

One, Change the data type in the database from Number to Decimal.

Two, Changing how I was defining the number as an int to a decimal.

Things work as I was wanting now. Thanks for the comments.